# Optimization in obtaining a list of IP conflicts from a Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, list, set, ip-address

I have a list of Network data containing the ID No., it's network IP and virtual IP. Sample shown below.

```
    ID  Network IP    Virtual IP
    1   10.1.1.0/24   -
    2   10.2.2.0/24   -
    3   10.3.3.0/24   10.4.4.88
    4   10.4.4.0/24   -
    5   10.1.0.0/16   -
    6   ...
    ...
    ...
```

The objective is to detect and output if there's any Network IP or Virtual IP conflicts/overlaps within the list which includes the resulting Network IP that conflicts and a Remark. `eg. Network IP conflict --> 10.1.1.0/24 overlaps with 10.1.0.0/16` and `Virtual-ip conflict --> 10.4.4.88 is in range of 10.4.4.0/24 (of different ID)`

Here's a sample output of the code.

```
ID  Network IP    Virtual IP    Result        Remark
5   10.1.0.0/16   -             10.1.0.0/16   Network Conflict
1   10.1.1.0/24   -             10.1.0.0/16   Network Conflict
3   10.3.3.0/24   10.4.4.88     10.4.4.0/24   Virtual-ip Conflict
4   10.4.4.0/24   -             10.4.4.0/24   Virtual-ip Conflict
```

Below is the sample code and currently I'm using nested "for" loops which is pretty slow. Hence, am just wondering if there's a more efficient algorithm to resolve this especially when it comes to comparing 100k+ Data?

```
import ipaddress

class Network:
    def __init__(self, ID='-', IPNet='-', VIP='-', Result='-', Remark='-'):
        self.ID = ID          # ID Number
        self.IPNet = IPNet    # Network IP
        self.VIP = VIP        # Virtual IP
        self.Result = Result  # Resulting Network IP that conflicts
        self.Remark = Remark
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.ID == other.ID and self.IPNet == other.IPNet and self.VIP == other.VIP and \
               self.Result == other.Result and self.Remark == other.Remark
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.ID, self.IPNet, self.VIP, self.Result, self.Remark))

Final_List = []
Input_List = [Network('1', '10.1.1.0/24', '-', '-', '-'),
              Network('2', '10.2.2.0/24', '-', '-', '-'),
              Network('3', '10.3.3.0/24', '10.4.4.88', '-', '-'),
              Network('4', '10.4.4.0/24', '-', '-', '-'),
              Network('5', '10.1.0.0/16', '-', '-', '-')]

for in1 in Input_List:
    IPNet1 = in1.IPNet
    for in2 in Input_List:
        IPNet2 = in2.IPNet

        # Resolving overlapping Network IP
        if in1.ID != in2.ID and ipaddress.ip_network(IPNet1).overlaps(ipaddress.ip_network(IPNet2)):
            Remark = 'Network Conflict'
            Result = '-'

            # Comparing size of network range. Resulting network IP will be the one with larger size
            size1 = ipaddress.ip_network(IPNet1).num_addresses
            size2 = ipaddress.ip_network(IPNet2).num_addresses
            if size1 >= size2:
                Result = IPNet1
            else:
                Result = IPNet2

            _in1 = Data(in1.ID, IPNet1, in1.VIP, Result, Remark)
            Final_List.append(_in1)
            _in2 = Data(in2.ID, IPNet2, in2.VIP, Result, Remark)
            Final_List.append(_in2)
            break
        # Resolving Virtual IP conflicts
        elif in1.ID != in2.ID and in1.VIP != '-' and ipaddress.ip_address(in1.VIP) in ipaddress.ip_network(IPNet2):
            Remark = 'Virtual-ip Conflict'
            Result = IPNet2
            _in1 = Data(in1.ID, IPNet1, in1.VIP, Result, Remark)
            Final_List.append(_in1)
            _in2 = Data(in2.ID, IPNet2, in2.VIP, Result, Remark)
            Final_List.append(_in2)
            break

Final_List = list(set(Final_List))  # Remove duplicates
Final_List = sorted(Final_List, key=lambda x: (ipaddress.ip_network(x.IPNet), x.ID), reverse=False)
```

Comment: very interesting question but you won't get much response, it's better if you provide a [mcve] with your expected output so others can test the solution

Comment: Please don't share code/data as images. Your code does not follow style conventions, and as such is quite difficult to read. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I don't know why you would use semicolons.

Comment: I'm working on translating/fixing the code, do you have any ideas for a better name than just "Data"? Also, can you explain the basic networking/IP notions required to understand the code?

Comment: @AMC Sorry, I've changed the name to "Network" instead, and I've added in a couple of comments within the code for a clearer picture... hope it helps and I've provided the examples of which if it's Network or Virtual IP conflict cases...

Comment: @AmosChew Great! I've made some changes, I'll share them in a bit.

Comment: By the way, would you be open to a solution which uses Pandas or something similar?

Comment: Yes that'd be great... am still in midst of exploring pandas for a solution as well..

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially store the data in a tree for faster lookup.

Comparing each IP network with the addresses in each other IP network requires a for loop over the number of networks, and likely a O(log n) algorithm to figure out whether they overlap. This makes your speed O(n^2 log n), which is pretty slow.

We can create a class called `IPTree` which splits the IPs based on their most significant bits. Should all your networks be in increments of 1 byte (`/32, /24, /16, /8`) as most common networks are, you can use a branching factor of 256 per tree level so that you don't need to explore down the tree as much. I will make this assumption based on your example, but if you want to support any type of network, you can split by bits instead of by bytes.

Now, our first node on the first level would be the root (none), the first level nodes would store the first byte (eg 10), the second level would store the second byte, the third level will store the third byte, and the fourth level will store the fourth byte. To mark a network as "taken", we simply need to toggle a flag in a node corresponding to the level where `L = n/8`, where n is the number of bits in the network mask.

But wait! Storing a full tree like this will take 2^32 integers! Surely we can reduce the amount of memory for only a few networks. We can do this by using a sparse tree.

Start with the root element, then for each network, add each byte of the network over to a level of the tree, marking the last node as an "end" node. The rest of the tree is just filled with `None`. The presence of a node, "end" or not, signifies that this point in the tree is at least partially used by another network or host, and therefore cannot be put in a new network. The presence of an "end" node signifies that this point in the tree is already occupied by a network and that you cannot put a network inside of it.

Here is a sketchy illustration of the solution, with green nodes representing "end" nodes:

[image: tree picture]

With this solution, we can complete a search and an add in O(32/b), where b is the number of bits per layer (8 for bytes, 1 for bits), which would make comparing n networks O(n/b). With constant b, this would scale with O(n).

Now, for the second part of your problem, you want to be able to figure out the IP addresses or networks that are conflicting with the network being added. There are two ways we can do this, each for different types of conflicts:

For a conflict where we have reached an "end" node, we know that we are trying to allocate an IP range or IP inside an already-occupied range, and we know what the occupied range is, as we have the corresponding "end" node. All we need to do is concatenate the node and each of its parents, pad the end with zeros, and append the number of bits in the network (which can be found by the count of the parent nodes). For example, trying to allocate 10.1.1.3 in the tree above will cause us to reach the end node at 10. -> 1. -> 1., which becomes 10.1.1.0/24. This will take O(1).

For a conflict where we have not reached an "end" node, but the node is already taken, we know we are trying to allocate an IP range that has an occupied IP range inside of it. For this, we simply perform a search of the child nodes to find the end nodes which are descendants of this node. This will take O(2^b * 32/b). With constant b, this would have a constant time efficiency.

Comment: Will this model catch the fact that `10.1.0.0/16` overlaps with `10.1.1.0/24`? If I understand your tree structure, it won't.

Comment: Once you add 10.1.1.0/24, to search for 10.1.0.0/16, you will find out that 10.1 already exists as a node. This means that something under 10.1 is currently in use, which means that 10.1.0.0/16 overlaps with something. To figure out what it overlaps with, we perform a search on everything under the 10.1 node for any end nodes. This includes 10.1.1.0/24 and any another /24 network under 10.1.

Comment: When it comes to resolving for IPv6, how about do we create the tree for it? ipaddress.ip_network(X).overlaps(ipaddress.ip_network(Y)) works for both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: For ipv6, simply use hex bytes (groups of 2 hex digits) instead of decimal values, or, if you want a better resolution, individual bits. You would need a slightly taller tree, though, as IPv6 has 16 bytes instead of 4.